# This task is no longer installed. Re-install the task or remove it from your pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I add a new release pipeline and select IIS Website deployment, the tasks show that some settings need attention.
[image: some settings need attention]

After setting the deployment group I still have a message that the task is no longer installed.

[image: no longer installed]

How do I fix that?

I have tried various settings in the right panel.

[Update]

Strangely when I now create a new pipeline I don't get the problem.

[Update] 
I am getting the problem again building a new release
I think the issue is connected with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545984/a-session-for-this-agent-already-exists)

Maybe it has something to do with the agent I am running. How do I associate a deployment with a release?

Comment: i might need to add a deployment group job first and then the tasks which means the template is missleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had been led astray by the options available on creating the release pipeline.

Instead of choosing a template I needed to choose

```
Start with an Empty Job
```

This will create a pipeline that has an Agent job in it.
Counter intuitively, the next step is to remove the Agent job

[image: remove the job]

Then add a deployment group job

[image: add a deployment group job]

Then add a Deployment group job to stage 1